# Use PKCS#12 file to distribute trusted CA certificates?

Tags: openssl

Is it possible to use PKCS#12 file to store multiple CA certificates (with no private key and these CA certificates are not in a chain) ?

I read about PKCS#12 and think this is do-able. However, all examples I found only use it to store private key and associated certificate chain.

Answer (score 2):

Sure: [PKCS#12](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292) is an "archive" format for cryptographic objects. It can contain pretty much whatever you want: multiple certificates, multiple private keys, etc. The encryption and signature is optional so you could use it for storing certificates.

[PKCS#7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315), however, is more commonly used for storing certificates: it's a simpler format that is specifically designed to hold X509 certificates without the corresponding private keys.

Comment: PKCS#7 specifies the Cryptographic Message Syntax. Is wasn't particularly designed to distribute *only* X.509 certificates but "A degenerate
   case of the syntax provides a means for disseminating certificates
   and certificate-revocation lists.". For *storing* certificates, especially in a *trust store* I'd rather use PKCS#12 myself.